# Why is this set open in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, connectedness

The original problem deals with proving that if a set $G\subset \mathbb C$ satisfies the condition 'for any $a,b\in G$, there is a polygon from $a$ to $b$ lying in $G$' then $G$ is connected.

By way of contradiction, we assume that there are nonempty disjoint open sets in  $G$, say $A,B$ whose union is $G$. The hypothesis implies that there is a line segment, from say $a\in A$ to say $b\in B$. If we define:

$$S=\{s\in [0,1]: bs+(1-s)a\in A\}$$ and

$$T=\{t\in [0,1]: bt+(1-t)a\in B\}$$

then it is clear that $S,T$ are nonempty disjoint sets in  $[0,1]$ whose union is $[0,1]$. I wish to show that $S,T$ are open.

To that end, if $s\in S$ then there must be an $\epsilon$ ball centered around $sb+(1-s)a\in A$. It is geometrically evident that $(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)\cap [0,1]$ is in $S$ but I am unable to establish this rigorously. A rigourous argument would prove that $S$ (and similarly $T$) is open, thereby completing the proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $bs+(1-s)a \in A$. There exists $r>0$ such that $B(bs+(1-s)a,r) \subset A$. If $|s-s'|<\frac r {|a|+|b|}$ then $$bs'+(1-s')a\in B(bs+(1-s)a,r)\subset A$$: $$|bs+(1-s)a-[bs'+(1-s')a]|$$ $$ \leq |s-s'||b|+|s-s'||a|<r.$$ [$|a|+|b|$ cannot be $0$].

[Notation: $B(c,r)=\{z \in G : |z-c|<r\}$]

Comment: Thank you. Minor quibble: Shouldn't you define $B(c,r)$ as $\{z\in G: |z-c|<r\}$?

Comment: @Shahab Right.  have corrected.